# XML to Excel and vice-versa

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros, xml

First of all, I am really not quite familiar with XML data, I mean I didn't work with them. I just got a question if I can do something with them using Excel, try to automate some things.

I could transform them using Power Query, to get proper data, but when I try to import them using the Developer tab (so the right way) I am getting like an error "no XML schema or something". And then on the right window, my Column names are shown (which is fine) and some "blue" empty boxes in the spreadsheet - when I hit refresh I got populated with values but without headers.

Any idea what is wrong and why I am getting an error?

Does XML file has to be so consistent as it is written on the code? I mean from the structure?

I will provide the code (I didn't write it!) and Screenshots of my issue.

My Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                                      Name=""
                                      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                      xmlns=""><Tablix1><Details_Collection>
```

```
Systemseriennummer="CSP10XXX"

    xPersonal="für Bediener und Wartungspersonal"
    Personal="für Installationspersonal"

    xName_Bedienungsanleitung="Installationsanleitung"
    yName_Bedienungsanleitung="Bedienungs- und Wartungsanleitung"

Verbleibende_Kapazitaet="10%"   

    Anschluss_Stickstoff="6 mm (1/4&quot;) Swagelok&#174; Schottverschraubung (oder kompatibel)"
    Anschluss_CDA="6 mm (1/4&quot;) Swagelok&#174; Schottverschraubung (oder kompatibel)"

    Kunde="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
 Herstellungsdatum="XX/2020"



 Prozess="XXXXXXXXXX" 

 Behandelte_Gase="F2, HF"
 Erlaubte_Gase="CHF3, SF6 reactive byproducts removed as HF, F2 &lt; 1 ppm &#13;N2, O2"
 Systemkonfiguration="025LS,CE3,D17,FM1,G00,GP3,MV2,QS0,SF2,TO1,UU1,VD2,VGA0,VGH0,VGP1"



 Befuellcode="ECXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"



 Befuellcode_MA="-"


 Gesamtgewicht_Saeule="XX kg"


    Sampling_Tiefe="XXX nur bei PD und PS"
 Hersteller_Gassensor="XXXXXXXXXXX"
    Gassensor_1="XXXXXXXXXX"
    Gassensor_2="-"

    Temperaturbereich="+5...+35°C"

Einlasskonzentration="max. 1 vol-%: F2 &#13;max. 4 vol-%: HF"
Auslasskonzentration="F2 (Fluorine) &lt; 1 ppm &#13;HF (Hydrogen fluoride) &lt; 1 ppm "
VGP="giftige, ätzende oder brennbare" 
xVGP="toxic, corrosive or flammable" 

    EL_Spannung="XXX momentan nur bei FST angeben"
    EL_Frequenz="XXX FST"                                                                                                               

     /></Details_Collection></Tablix1></Report>
```

XML export data:
[XML Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAHJy.gif)

Extracted values but no header names:

[Extract from xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wh9J3.gif)

An error after upload
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7Hrm.gif)

Comment: What research have you done before writing this question? e.g. https://www.wikihow.com/Convert-XML-to-Excel

Comment: @DrMoishePippik 
https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/xml.html   https://spreadsheeto.com/xml/
https://www.tabellenexperte.de/von-excel-zu-xml-und-zurueck/ 

And google... as I say, I am still getting an error, says the Schema is missing. I know how to import..